# How to determine the process is done in python

Tags: pysvn

I used **pysvn** to Check out a working copy from a repository, how can I determine that checking out is completed to give the message to the user?

```
client = pysvn.Client() 
client.checkout('file:///media/sda5/trunk','/tmp/test_checkout')
```

I used the above code to check out, so how can determine when it's done?

Please give me some ideas. Thanks

Comment: do you use it in a GUI or ina python script?

Comment: so give code and details

Comment: @CharlesB

`client = pysvn.Client()
client.checkout('file:///media/sda5/trunk','/tmp/test_checkout')`

I want to determine when the checking out is done.

Comment: please edit the question instead;

Comment: @CharlesB

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: see `pysvn.wc_notify_action.update_completed` http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_notify

Comment: do you mean the checkout function returns immediately, not waiting for the checkout to complete?

Comment: @CharlesB, I'm not sure. Let met check it out. thanks

Comment: @CharlesB, thank for your questions. It will be waiting for the checkout to complete. I am a newbie, so I didn't test it all cases. THANK.

Comment: great. added an answer so you can accept and/or upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client.checkout` operation is waiting for the checkout to complete, so just notify it the way you want after function return.